# useState in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can anyone tell me how to transfer it to form acceptable in class component? Thanks

```
const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(localStorage.getItem("isAuth"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following

- define the state in the constructor and initialize it with the value you use in the `useState`
- create a `setIsAuth` method that sets the state to the new value passed

---

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component{
 
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuth: localStorage.getItem("isAuth")
    }
  }

  setIsAuth = (newValue) => {
    this.setState({
      isAuth: newValue
    });
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```